# I want to create two Prolog relations and place their definitions in a single Prolog file

Tags: prolog

I want to create two Prolog relations and place their definitions in a single Prolog file. Define the relations prefix and postfix on lists, meaning that the first argument is a prefix or postfix, respectively, of the second.

```
?- consult(prepost).

% prepost compiled 0.00 sec, 956 bytes

true.


?- prefix([a,b,c],[a,b,c,e,f]).

true.

?- prefix([a,b,c], [a,b,e,f]).

false.

?- prefix([a,b],[a]).

false.


?- prefix([],[a,b,c,d]).

true.

?- prefix(X,[a,b,c,d]).

X = [] ;

X = [a] ;

X = [a, b] ;

X = [a, b, c] ;

X = [a, b, c, d] ;

false.

?- postfix([n,e],[d,o,n,e]).
true .

?- postfix([],[a,n,y,t,h,i,n,g]).

true .

?- postfix([a,b,c],[a,b,c,d,e]).

false.

?- postfix(X,[a,b,c,d]).

X = [a, b, c, d] ;

X = [b, c, d] ;

X = [c, d] ;

X = [d] ;

X = [] ;

false.

?-
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the predicate `append/3` to solve your problem in a simple way.
A list of elements is prefix of some other list, if there is a combination where this first list concatenated with another (not relevant), results in your full list.

```
prefix(Prefix_list, Full_list):- append(Prefix_list, _, Full_list).
```

You can infer your predicate `postfix/2` in the same way:

```
postfix(Postfix_list, Full_list):- append(_, Postfix_list, Full_list).
```

Now, put both predicate in a text file, name it `prepost.pl`, and that's it.